# Alternative to dataset for IE8 (sorting elements by data attribute)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me get this script working for IE8? It works fine in Mozilla and WebKit browsers, but throws an error in IE8: 'dataset.numValue' is null or not an object.

```
var $wrapper = $('#containerInner'),
  $sorted = $wrapper.find('.sortMe').get().sort(function (a, b) {
    return +a.dataset.numValue - +b.dataset.numValue;
  });
```

I know IE8 supports data attributes... but can't figure out or find on Google an answer to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) of jQuery instead of dataset.

```
var $wrapper = $('#containerInner'),
  $sorted = $wrapper.find('.sortMe').get().sort(function (a, b) {
    return +$(a).data("numValue") - + $(b).data("numValue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `$(el).data('key')`. To store data on an element using markup simply use the `data-key` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to get this value.